# Cannot Install Plotly in R

Tags: r, installation, plotly

Attempting to install plotly in R studio 3.6.1 on a work computer.

Running into this error.

`Error in if (any(diff)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Traceback gives

```
4: tools::checkMD5sums(pkgname, file.path(tmpDir, pkgname))
3: unpackPkgZip(foundpkgs[okp, 2L], foundpkgs[okp, 1L], lib, libs_only, 
       lock)
2: .install.winbinary(pkgs = bins, lib = lib, contriburl = contrib.url(repos, 
       type2), method = method, available = av2, destdir = destdir, 
       dependencies = NULL, libs_only = libs_only, quiet = quiet, 
       ...)
1: install.packages("plotly")
```

Is the checksum not passing? Why would this be?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try another CRAN mirror? You can do that by running `chooseCRANmirror()` before `install.packages()`. That does seem like an odd error.

Comment: Definitely tried many mirrors. Also tried downloading the package and installing from a local zipfile. Same error.